# How to specify what devices are to be considered mobile?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

ASP.NET MVC 4 has a handy feature where by adding a .Mobile to the View, the engine will automatically serve it out to mobile devices.  Works great for iPhones, WP7, etc... devices.

Except for Android devices - for whatever reason, it serves the desktop version for them.

I am assuming that the framework figures out whether the browser is mobile or not based on the definitions in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers`.

Unfortunately the folder contains no entry for an Android browsers:
[image]

Where can I get a definition for an android browser?

Comment: Take a look at this blog post, it might have the information that you are looking for: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/12/17/using-51degreesmobi-foundation-for-accurate-mobile-browser-detection-on-aspnet-mvc-3/

Answer (score 1):

It's just an XML file. [Browser Definition File Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122.aspx) You would need to copy it to every server you deploy to. A better approach is to use the 51Degrees.Mobi package. See [Steve Sandersons blog.](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/12/17/using-51degreesmobi-foundation-for-accurate-mobile-browser-detection-on-aspnet-mvc-3/)
Application-level browser-definition files can be placed in the application's App_Browsers directory. That's probably a better place.

Answer (score 0):

I think It was caused by your mobile indicator file. please check /App_Browsers/MobileBrowserData/mobile.browser and add Android devices.

Comment: I can't find a file like that anywhere.

Comment: You have to create App_Browsers. Application-level browser-definition files can be placed in the application's App_Browsers directory - but you have to do that.